# When I click on Install App, nothing happens

Tags: upgrade, mac-appstore, install, macos

I am trying to install Mavericks on my 2009 Macbook Pro running OS 10.7.5.

When I click on Install App in the App Store, Mavericks doesn't install. Either nothing happens, or a spinner briefly appears at the top and then disappears.

An I doing something wrong here? I've never used the App Store before, so maybe there's something I'm missing. The first time I was prompted for my Apple password, which I put in.

[Here's a video I made of what happens.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vs1a_xhwy3I)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by doing the following

- Turn on the Debug Menu in the App Store using

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
  ```
- Using the Debug Menu, clear cookies and reset the application
- Open the Downloads directory and delete the com.apple.appstore folder
- Quit the App Store and kill the storeagent process
- Try to install again

I had to do the above steps a couple times before I got it to work.